# how to make a temporary collection in meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, spacebars

As a preface: I'm pretty new to Meteor.

My goal: I'm trying to make a site that stores vegetables as a collection, stores recipes (which contain the ingredients needed) as a collection, and will display to the user a list of recipes based on if they have an ingredient the user has checkmarked.  Only the recipes containing the checkmarked ingredients will be displayed.

To do this I want to create a temporary collection that contains the checkmarked ingredients and use it to identify which recipes to display.  I tried using a session, but I don't know if I can insert/remove and find items from a session, so I would prefer to use a collection.  However, if multiple users are using the website at the same time, I don't want the collection to recieve interference, so I want the collection to be unique to each visitor (client side and temporary, like a sesson)

so far, I have the following code:

**template to display vegetables:**

```
<template name="veggies">
  <ul>
    {{#each vegetables}}
      <li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked" />
        <span class="text">{{vegetable}}</span>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="button">
  <button class="submit">Sugest recipes</button>
</template>
```

**Javascript file code for the vegetables:**

```
Recipes = new Mongo.Collection('recipes');
vegetables = new Mongo.Collection('vegetable');


if (Meteor.isClient) {


// VEGGIES

  // this displays the vegetables
  Template.veggies.helpers({
    'vegetables': function() {
      return vegetables.find()
    }

  });

  // this selects toggles the check mark
  Template.veggies.events({
    "click .toggle-checked": function () {
      this._id, {$set: {checked: ! this.checked}};
      var ItemID = this._id
      Session.set('selectedVeggies', ItemID);
    },
  });

  // this submits the request and reveals possible recipes
  Template.button.events({
    "click .submit": function () {
      Session.set('PossibleRecipes', true);
    }
  });
```

So - I need to know if there is a way to accomplish this task.  I could hard-code all the ingredients in as boolean variables and then make the possible recipes display based on which boolean values were true, but this seems time consuming and I'd rather create a dynamic system in which the list of vegetable/ingredients and recipes can be added to / subtracted from easily.

Answer (score 6):

To create a client-side collection, just don't give it a name argument.

```
// This collection has a name, and will work on both the server and client
Recipes = new Mongo.Collection('recipes');

// This collection is client-only, and does not have a name.
// It will not be synchronized with the server.
Vegetables = new Mongo.Collection();

// To be more explicit, you can use `null` for the name:
Meats = new Mongo.Collection(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Now my second question is: is it possible to insert a document copied from one collection into another?

Comment: You mean like: `Collection1.insert(Collection2.findOne());`

Comment: I created a client side colletion called CheckedVeggies:

    CheckedVeggies = new Mongo.Collection('null');

  Template.veggies.events({
    "click .toggle-checked": function () {
      this._id, {$set: {checked: ! this.checked}};
      var ItemID = this._id;
      CheckedVeggies.insert(vegetables.find({vegetable: ItemID}).fetch());
    },
  });

this doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @SamLouisMilligan The `collection.insert` method expects one document. Instead of fetching, you'll need to iterate through the cursor with [`cursor.forEach`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/foreach) and insert each document in the cursor.

Answer (score -3):

You can use client-side only collection. Read my article for details: http://meteor.hromnik.com/blog/array-of-objects-as-a-client-side-collection-in-meteor